# What preposition do I use  -- on, to, for, -- when writing "stand for election" for a group?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, to-for

Hopefully this is a simple question, although possibly too simple for this site - if so I apologise!

Which, if any, are acceptable phrases:

> ...stand for election **on** a place on the group
>
> ...stand for election **to** a place on the group
>
> ...stand for election **for** a place on the group

I'm immediately drawn to the final option, but the use of 'for election for' bugs me somewhat - I don't know why.

Comment: Im not sure if I understand your examples.

Comment: I touched up the formatting a bit. Do you mind adding some sample words in each of your examples? The second ellipsis is a bit distracting.

Comment: they're pretty much unnecessary - cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BE you stand for an election for a place but to a body.
So election **to** a parliament **for** a constituency.

You can also stand **on** a platform - where platform is a policy. eg standing on a platform for tax-cuts.

Comment: In AmE, elections are not stood for.

Comment: Thanks Martin.. my case is BE and your answer makes things a lot more simple.

Comment: @Peter, to be fair we can't really stand them either - but there doesn't seem to be any workable alternative

Comment: I don't thing I've ever heard of a candidate "standing on a platform" in AE, except maybe in the most literal sense. A candidate can be said to stand for a position or issue--"he stands for tax cuts"--although we would be much more likely to simply say "He supports tax cuts."

Comment: @Martin: Googling, I find that it appears that candidates "stand on a platform" in England, Scotland, Australia, and Singapore, but not usually in the U.S. In AmE, we would *run for election* and *run on a platform of tax cuts.* Strangely, though, despite running instead of standing, our politicians don't appear to be any more athletic than yours.